# How to make a div scrollable from left to right

Tags: jquery, css

So heres the css for the div that should be scrollable

```
.form-holder{
        padding-left: 20px;
        width: auto;
        background: ;
        overflow: auto;
        max-height: 300px;
        padding-bottom: 30px;

    }
```

each time I upload image preview is available and i wanted those image be viewed horizontally not vertically. so I wanted the div to be scrollable left to right

heres the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/roowako/AZvuL/

Comment: You can check this plugin for scroll http://jquerytools.org/demos/scrollable/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming this is what you want to create :

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/W6rSg/9/)**

HTML :

```
<div class="form-holder">
    <div class="img_wrap">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-280-280-4.jpg" />
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/sports-q-c-280-280-2.jpg" />
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-280-280-9.jpg" />
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/fashion-q-c-280-280-1.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.form-holder {
    padding-left: 20px;
    width: 300px;
    background: grey;
    overflow: auto;
    max-height: 300px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}
.img_wrap {
    width: 1120px;  /*width of all images */
}
.form-holder img {
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: yes something like this. but images are added thru javascript. heres my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/roowako/AZvuL/

Comment: @Ruther Ok so you will have to use you script to calculate the number of images to insert in `.img_wrap` so you can calculate sum of their withs and set is on the `.img_wrap` so it can contain them all.

Comment: i need 15 reputations to up hehe.

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery and [Mouse Wheel Plugin](https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel) to bind a `mousewheel` event on the div you want to have a horizontal scrolling on.

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#divId').mousewheel(function(e, delta) {
    this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 30);
    e.preventDefault();
});
});
</script>
```

You can change the number multiplied by `delta` (30 in my example) to set the number of pixels moved on each scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Limit the `width` of your div if you want to scroll horizontally

```
.form-holder{
        padding-left: 20px;
        width: 300px;
        background: ;
        overflow: auto;
        max-height: 300px;
        padding-bottom: 30px;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s6AsC/

You have to limit the size and set the `overflow-x` to `auto`

```
.form-holder{
        padding-left: 20px;
        height: 300px; /* if you want to set the height */
        width: 300px;
        background: ;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        overflow-x: auto;
        max-height: 300px;
        padding-bottom: 30px;

    }
```